# Return longest string if key is duplicated

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have data like:

```
   key   value
   k1    string1
   k2    Other string 
   k3    Long string 
   k1    
   k3    string
```

Some of them could be empty.

I want to return longest value if key is duplicated. So the result should be like:

```
   key   value
   k1    string1
   k2    Other string 
   k3    Long string
```

My code (with solving memo field aggregating):

```
"IIF(COUNT(key)=1, " & _
                    "MAX(IIF(LEN(value)>250, " & _
                                          "'[CUT]' & LEFT(value, 245), " & _
                                            value & "))," & _
                    "MAX(IIF(LEN(value)>250, " & _
                                            "'[[CUT]' & LEFT(value, 245) & ']', " & _
                                            "'[' & value & ']' ))) AS " & value
```

The thing is that I want to return longest string from duplicates. Now I use `MAX` function but this return value due to alphabetical order so if value is empty it returns empty.

I am getting data using ADODB with

```
[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text'HDR=YES;']
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple values with the same max lenght?

Comment: This should not happen. Second of duplicated key is usually empty. But if this happens then alphabetical order could be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where len(t.value) = (select max(len(t2.value))
                      from t t2
                      where t2.key = t.key
                     );
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add `MAX()` into your subquery like `... where len(t.value) = (select MAX(len(t2.value))`

Comment: Well, thank you but I am thinking before implementing this into my quite complicated code how this code deals with key duplicates? I have more columns in the table where is need to apply this and creating subquery for each does not seem to me very effective. I use code above (IIF) for each of my columns - so maybe modifying it would be easier.

Comment: @MichalPalko . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask:  "I want to return longest value if key is duplicated. "  If you have a different or more detailed question, please ask it as a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I offer this answer which can deal with multiple `my_value` values of the same length.

This resolves the issue in an arbitrary way using MAX and assumes all values of the MAX length are of equal fitness.

As pointed out in the comments by @TheImpaler this step may be necessary depending on your data set and need.

```
SELECT CAST('k1' as varchar(2)) as my_key, CAST('string1' as varchar(100)) as my_value INTO my_table;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k1', NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k2', 'Other string'); 
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k2', 'sneak string'); 
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k2', NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k3', 'Long string');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k3', 'string');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('k3', 'sneaky');

WITH s1
as
(
SELECT t.my_key
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.my_value) as my_value_options_total_count
      ,MAX(LEN(t.my_value)) as my_value_max_len  
  FROM my_table t
 WHERE t.my_value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.my_key
)
SELECT t.my_key
     ,s1.my_value_options_total_count
     ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.my_value) as my_value_options_max_len_count
     ,MAX(t.my_value) as my_value_resolved
  FROM my_table t INNER JOIN s1
    ON t.my_key = s1.my_key
   AND LEN(t.my_value) = s1.my_value_max_len
 GROUP BY t.my_key,s1.my_value_options_total_count
 ORDER BY t.my_key;
```

This article has more on [Common Table Expressions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/).

Here are the results...

```
+----+--------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
|    | my_key | my_value_options_total_count | my_value_options_max_len_count | my_value_resolved |
+----+--------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | k1     |                            1 |                              1 | string1           |
|  2 | k2     |                            2 |                              2 | sneak string      |
|  3 | k3     |                            3 |                              1 | Long string       |
+----+--------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+
```

I created the ASCII table using [this tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Gordon's solution I added an outer `group by` to deal with duplicate strings of the same length:

```
select id,min(val) val from my_table t
where len(val)=(
  select max(len(t2.val))
  from my_table t2
  where t2.id= t.id
)
and len(val)>0 
group by id
```

You can find a working demo here: https://rextester.com/KTSF40897